# Unable to set the correct position and width for my site

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Hello I want to put the header on the whole width of the screen and the images align but I could not, how to do ?

I have already tried to add to the header `width:100%;` and `position: static;` but nothing changes

**HTML Code ( index.html ) :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Disusa</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<main>
<header class="header">
  <div class="navbar">
        <div class="search-container">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Que voulez vous comparer...">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    <div class="icons-container">
      <a href="#profile" class="icon-link"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
      <a href="#panier" class="icon-link"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </div>
    </div>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home" id="home">Accueil</a></li>
      <li><a href="#allproducts" id="project">Tout les produits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#settings" id="about">Paramétres</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" id="how">Nous contacter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<body>
  <div class="imgs_home">
  <figure class="img_home">
    <img class="img3" src="./Picture/pc premonter.jpg" alt="PC Premonter" />
    <figcaption>
      <h3>PC <span>Prémonter</span></h3>
    </figcaption>
    <a href="#pc-premonter"></a>
  </figure>
  <figure class="img_home" class="img_poupout">
    <img class="img1" src="./Picture/pc montage.jpg" alt="PC Custom" />
    <figcaption>
      <h3>PC <span>Custom</span></h3>
    </figcaption>
    <a href="#custom"></a>
  </figure>
  <figure class="img_home">
    <img class="img2" src="./Picture/pc portable.jpg" alt="PC Portable" />
    <figcaption>
      <h3>PC <span>Portable</span></h3>
    </figcaption>
    <a href="#pc-protable"></a>
  </figure>
  </div>
</main>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code ( style.css ) :**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
/* Style de la barre de navigation */
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
/* Style des icônes */
.icon-link {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.fa-user, .fa-shopping-cart {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* Rendre les icônes noir */
}
.fa-shopping-cart:hover, .fa-user:hover { /* faire changer de couleur lors de son survol */
    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
  }
/*                   ---- barre de recherche ----           */
.search-container { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: width 0.5s ease; /* transition fluide de la largeur */
    width: 75% ;
  }
.search-container input[type=text] {
  width:  450px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.search-container button {
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.search-container button:hover{
    background: rgb(214, 214, 214);
}
.fa-search {
  border-radius: 20px; /* Ajouter cette propriété pour rendre l'icône de recherche arrondi */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .search-container {
        width: 60%; /* largeur réduite pour les fenêtres plus petites */
      }
}
/*                   ---- barre de recherche ----           */
.main_title{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#welcome{ 
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.img1{
    width: 370px;
    height: 208px;
    width: 100%;
}
.imgs_home{
    text-align: center;
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,700;);
.img_home {
  background-color: rgb(41, 46, 57);
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 370px;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.img_home * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease;
  transition: all 0.45s ease;
}

.img_home:before,
.img_home:after {
  background-color: rgba(46, 52, 64,  0.5);
  border-top: 50px solid rgba(46, 52, 64, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 50px solid rgba(46, 52, 64, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.img_home:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(2);
  transform: scaleY(2);
}

.img_home:after {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(2);
  transform: scaleY(2);
}

.img_home img {
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.img_home figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.img_home h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.img_home h3 span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.img_home a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.img_home:hover > img {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.img_home:hover:before,
.img_home:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.img_home:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 100px) {
    .img_home {
      width: 50%; /* largeur réduite pour les fenêtres plus petites */
    }
    .search-container {
        width: 40%; /* largeur réduite pour les fenêtres plus petites */
      }
}
```

**CSS Code ( test.css ) base code as scss and transform to css code :**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mona Sans";
  src: url("https://assets.codepen.io/64/Mona-Sans.woff2") format("woff2 supports variations"), url("https://assets.codepen.io/64/Mona-Sans.woff2") format("woff2-variations");
  font-weight: 100 1000;
}
@layer properties {
  @property --after-bg-position {
    syntax: "<number>";
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 0;
  }
  @property --after-radial-bg-position {
    syntax: "<number>";
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 0;
  }
  @property --after-bg-width {
    syntax: "<number>";
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 100;
  }
  @property --after-bg-opacity {
    syntax: "<number>";
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 20;
  }
  @property --after-shadow-offset {
    syntax: "<number>";
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 15;
  }
  @property --after-scale {
    syntax: "<number>";
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 0.85;
  }
  @property --li-before-opacity {
    syntax: "<number>";
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 0;
  }
}
:root {
  /* -- Colors: */
  --body-bg-color: hsl(221deg 16% 6%);
  /* -- Background */
  --bg-position: 0;
  /* -- misc */
  --debug: 0;
  --trs-easing: cubic-bezier(.41,-0.09,.55,1.09);
  --trs-timing: 300ms;
  --trs-delay: 80ms;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* debug */
  outline: calc(var(--debug) * 1px) dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: var(--body-bg-color);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-family: "Mona Sans", sans-serif;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
main header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 6em;
}

.nav {
  transition: --after-bg-position var(--trs-timing) var(--trs-easing) 0.2s, --after-radial-bg-position var(--trs-timing) var(--trs-easing) 0.2s, --after-bg-width var(--trs-timing) var(--trs-easing) 0.2s, --after-bg-opacity var(--trs-timing) var(--trs-easing) 0.2s, --li-before-opacity var(--trs-timing) var(--trs-easing) 0.2s;
  background: var(--body-bg-color);
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.nav:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(var(--after-bg-width) * 1px - 8px);
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255 255 255/calc(var(--after-shadow-offset) * 1%));
  border-radius: 100px;
  filter: blur(20px);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--after-bg-position) * 1px)) scale(1.1);
}
.nav ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse 150px 100px at calc(var(--after-radial-bg-position) * 1px) bottom, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
  /*
   &:has(li.active:hover):after {
    --after-bg-opacity: 50;
    --after-shadow-offset: 10;
  }
  */
  /* 
    Some :has() goodness to control the 
    nav:after border-radius hihihi 
  */
}
.nav ul:active {
  --after-scale: 0.75 ;
}
.nav ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  background: var(--body-bg-color);
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: calc(var(--after-bg-width) * 1px - 12px);
  height: calc(100% - 12px);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(255 255 255/calc(var(--after-bg-opacity, 0) / 10 * 1%)), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1));
  box-shadow: inset 0 -6px calc(var(--after-shadow-offset, 0) * 1px) rgb(255 255 255/calc(var(--after-bg-opacity) * 1%));
  left: 6px;
  top: 6px;
  transform: translate(calc(var(--after-bg-position) * 1px), 0);
  border-radius: 100px 12px 12px 100px;
  transition: --after-bg-opacity var(--trs-timing) var(--trs-easing) var(--trs-delay), --after-shadow-offset var(--trs-timing) var(--trs-easing) var(--trs-delay), border-radius var(--trs-timing) var(--trs-easing) var(--trs-delay);
  pointer-events: none;
}
.nav ul li {
  padding: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.nav ul li:not(.active):hover {
  --li-before-opacity: 0.3;
}
.nav ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35));
  opacity: var(--li-before-opacity);
  transform: scale(var(--after-scale)) rotateY(calc(var(--tilt-bg-y) * 3 * -1deg)) rotateX(calc(var(--tilt-bg-x) * 3 * 1deg)) translateZ(15px);
  transition: --li-before-opacity var(--trs-timing) var(--trs-easing), --after-scale calc(var(--trs-timing) / 2) var(--trs-easing) calc(var(--trs-delay) / 2);
}
.nav ul li:first-of-type:before {
  border-radius: 100px 12px 12px 100px;
}
.nav ul li:last-of-type:before {
  border-radius: 12px 100px 100px 12px;
}
.nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.nav ul:has(li.active:first-of-type a):after {
  border-radius: 100px 12px 12px 100px;
}
.nav ul:has(li.active:last-of-type a):after {
  border-radius: 12px 100px 100px 12px;
}
.nav ul:has(li.active:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) a):after {
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

**JavaScript Code ( main.js ) :**

```
var snippet = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.hover'));
if (snippet.length) {
  snippet.forEach(function (snippet) {
    snippet.addEventListener('mouseout', function (event) {
      if (event.target.parentNode.tagName === 'figure') {
        event.target.parentNode.classList.remove('hover')
      } else {
        event.target.parentNode.classList.remove('hover')
      }
    });
  });
}
function inverseMousePosition(element, event) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top;

  const res = {
    x1: -(x - rect.width / 2) / 20, // top left
    y1: -(y - rect.height / 2) / 20,
    x2: -(x - rect.width / 2) / 20, // top right
    y2: (y - rect.height / 2) / 20,
    x3: (x - rect.width / 2) / 20, // bottom left
    y3: -(y - rect.height / 2) / 20,
    x4: (x - rect.width / 2) / 20, // bottom right
    y4: (y - rect.height / 2) / 20
  };

  const resKey =
    "x" + (x < rect.width / 2 ? 1 : 2) + (y < rect.height / 2 ? 1 : 3);
  const tilt = res;
  return tilt !== undefined ? tilt : 0; // default to 0 if undefined
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please produce a [mre], you currently have a lot of code in the question that doesn't seem related to positioning a header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
#header
{
  width:100%;
  height:20%;   // the desired height
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

I believe position:absolute is what you're looking for. See:
[How to change header and footer to full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551730/how-to-change-header-and-footer-to-full-width)